# Xcode 11, where can I manage Build Phase?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I've migrated my app into Xcode 11.

I want to remove legacy resources that copied at Build Phase, but I can't find old `Build Phase` menu.

[image: Xcode 11 Build settings...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that you have selected **Target** instead of **Project**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the project selected (in the "project and targets list", which may be a collapsed pane for your Xcode).

So first, make sure the button to the far left of the "Info" tab shown in your screenshot is toggled on (so you can see your project and targets list).

Then simply select a target.  Now you'll see the Build Phases tab.  Only the targets of a project have build phases.

Note: If you don't like to keep the targets list shown, you can simply use the popup menu next to the pane's toggle button - which appears when the pane is not shown - to toggle from project to a target.